# Associative array inside for loop

Tags: php, associative-array

I have written a code in which I want to add some data in a associative array. I wanted to use array_push but I thought I should ask the community for this practice. Am I doing this the correct way? What I want to achieve is that for each index of for loop data should be added to the array but here a new instance is created each time I think. The options is the array and the id_option and name should be in each index of the array like when finding the data it should be `$options[0]['id_option']`.

```
for ($mn = 0; $mn < sizeof($pages); $mn++) {
    $options = array(
        array(
            'id_option' => $pages[$mn]['meta_title'],
            'name' => $pages_links[$mn]['link'],
        )
    );
}
```

I also tried it this way but this doesn't work, syntax error in the one below (that's only for theoretical purposes:

```
$options = array(
    for ($mn = 0; $mn < sizeof($pages); $mn++) {
        array(
            'id_option' => $pages[$mn]['meta_title'],
            'name' => $pages_links[$mn]['link'],
        )
    }
);
```

Comment: How about changing the line `$options = array(` to `$options[] = array(`?

Comment: I can try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$options = array();//init the array options

for ($mn = 0; $mn < sizeof($pages); $mn++) {
    $options[] = array(
        'id_option' => $pages[$mn]['meta_title'],
        'name' => $pages_links[$mn]['link'],
    );
}

print_r($options);
```

note the bracklet after the $option variable - this will tell PHP to add a value to the array $options

Comment: This is giving me what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to add it, not overwrite it, so use `$options[] = x`.

And good practice is to define the empty array above the loop, so in the other part of the code you would at least have an array to work with (empty or not), instead of undefined var.

```
// define $options as an array
$options = [];

// add array with data to $options array
for ($mn = 0; $mn < sizeof($pages); $mn++) {
    $options[] = [
        'id_option' => $pages[$mn]['meta_title'],
        'name' => $pages_links[$mn]['link'],
     ];
}
```

I also removed the 2nd nested array.

Comment: I tried this too. It is working but the one I selected was more close to my code. +1 :D

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
$options = array();

for ($mn = 0; $mn < sizeof($pages); $mn++)
{
    $options[$mn] = array();
    $options[$mn]['id_option'] = $pages[$mn]['meta_title'];
    $options[$mn]['name'] = $pages_links[$mn]['link'];
}
```

Comment: $options.push , this look like a mix with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your second code won't work. But you can change your first code a little bit and make it working.

```
$options = []; // defines the array
for ($mn = 0; $mn < sizeof($pages); $mn++) {
    $options[] = array(
            'id_option' => $pages[$mn]['meta_title'],
            'name' => $pages_links[$mn]['link'],
    );
}
```

- *$options = []* defines the array
- Then the for loop loops through your data.
- Each time the loop runs, PHP creates new associative array with array() function and add that to the $options array as a new element.
- Finally you'll get a multi dimensional array. ($options)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing above will overwrite the options array every time.

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but try something like this:

```
$options = array();

for ($mn = 0; $mn < sizeof($pages); $mn++) {
   $key = $pages[$mn]['meta_title'];
   $value = $pages_links[$mn]['link'];
   $options[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($options);
```

Since I don't know what your original data looks like, it is a little hard to test, whether this will work.

Hope it helps.